# Focus (nextKeyView) in a tableview flowing from line to line

Tags: swift, macos, focus, nstableview, nstablecellview

In my example I have tableview

```
  @IBOutlet weak var tableview: NSTableView!
```

if for example the second textfield in line 2 "Dr" has the focus, I want to focus the first textfield in line 3 "tom" after a "tab"

I can do it "explicitly" row for row in the tableview like this:

```
tableview.view(atColumn: 0, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: true)?.subviews[1].nextKeyView = tableview.view(atColumn: 0, row: 1, makeIfNecessary: true)?.subviews[0]
```

but I think that´s very unelegant.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

[image]
[image]